# Scipy.optimize minimize error for Neural Network

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network

I'm building a neural network and trying to optimize the theta parameters using the minimize function from scipy.optimize.

An interesting thing is happening. When I build the network with just the first 1,000 rows of data (by using nrows=1000), the minimize function works fine. But when I change nrows=2000, the code I run returns the output which i screenshotted in the link below.

Code:

```
fmin = minimize(fun=backprop, x0=params, args=(input_size, hidden_size, num_labels, X, y, learning_rate), 
            method='TNC', jac=True, options={'maxiter': 250})
```

[Screenshot of Output with nrows=2000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBng0.jpg)

Since I'm using the back-propagation and truncated newton algorithms, I assumed it could be because of NA values in my data. Hence, I began the process by running:

```
train.fillna(train.mean())
```

But that still led to the output above. Any idea why? For your reference, below is my back propagation function and a screenshot of output with nrows=1000.

```
def backprop(params, input_size, hidden_size, num_labels, X, y, learning_rate):
m = X.shape[0]
X = np.matrix(X)
y = np.matrix(y)

# reshape the parameter array into parameter matrices for each layer
theta1 = np.matrix(np.reshape(params[:hidden_size * (input_size + 1)], (hidden_size, (input_size + 1))))
theta2 = np.matrix(np.reshape(params[hidden_size * (input_size + 1):], (num_labels, (hidden_size + 1))))

# run the feed-forward pass
a1, z2, a2, z3, h = forward_propagate(X, theta1, theta2)

# initializations
J = 0
delta1 = np.zeros(theta1.shape)  # (25, 401)
delta2 = np.zeros(theta2.shape)  # (10, 26)

# compute the cost
for i in range(m):
    first_term = np.multiply(-y[i,:], np.log(h[i,:]))
    second_term = np.multiply((1 - y[i,:]), np.log(1 - h[i,:]))
    J += np.nansum(first_term - second_term)

J = J / m

# add the cost regularization term
J += ((learning_rate) / (2 * m)) * (np.nansum(np.power(theta1[:,1:], 2)) + np.nansum(np.power(theta2[:,1:], 2)))

# perform backpropagation
for t in range(m):
    a1t = a1[t,:]  # (1, 401)
    z2t = z2[t,:]  # (1, 25)
    a2t = a2[t,:]  # (1, 26)
    ht = h[t,:]  # (1, 10)
    yt = y[t,:]  # (1, 10)

    d3t = ht - yt  # (1, 10)

    z2t = np.insert(z2t, 0, values=np.ones(1))  # (1, 26)
    d2t = np.multiply((theta2.T * d3t.T).T, sigmoid_gradient(z2t))  # (1, 26)

    delta1 = delta1 + (d2t[:,1:]).T * a1t
    delta2 = delta2 + d3t.T * a2t

delta1 = delta1 / m
delta2 = delta2 / m

# add the gradient regularization term
delta1[:,1:] = delta1[:,1:] + (theta1[:,1:] * learning_rate) / m
delta2[:,1:] = delta2[:,1:] + (theta2[:,1:] * learning_rate) / m

# unravel the gradient matrices into a single array
grad = np.concatenate((np.ravel(delta1), np.ravel(delta2)))

return J, grad
```

[Output with nrows=1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueP71.jpg)

I'm also aware the additional data added more LabelEncoder() and OneHotEncoder() values - but I'm not quite sure if those contributed to the error. Any help would be great guys, thanks!

Comment: How many iterations does it take to converge with nrows=1000? What happens when you increase maxiter when nrows=2000?

Comment: Double check that your gradient is computed correctly. The error messages look like there's an error in the gradient vector your code computes.